# How can I fight the wall of flesh without killing the guide?

Tags: terraria

I'm nearing hardmode, but I have moral objections to sacrificing the Guide in order to fight the Wall of Flesh. Even in a silly video game I don't want to be that evil.

Is there a way to summon the Wall of Flesh without sacrificing the Guide?

I'm not interested in solutions like "accidentally kill a voodoo demon over the lava", I want to actually not kill the Guide.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, the fact that the Guide knows so much, wants Crimstone for *something*, and the fact that killing him spawns an unholy demon would suggest that the guide is more sinister than he appears.

Comment: If you're averse to doing the deed yourself, you could try slaying a Voodoo Demon while he's over lava.  This way you can at least try to tell yourself, "I didn't do it.".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same feelings when I was ready to enter Hardmode. There apparently is *not* a way to summon the Wall of Flesh or any other bosses from the vanilla console, but there are mods.

I used [TShock](https://tshock.co/), a Terraria server that lets you spawn any boss (among other things). It worked nicely, and if you want to quit using it after you beat the Wall of Flesh, that's fine - it's an external server, so there's nothing to uninstall from your game.

1. Back up your saves! Just because it's better to be safe than sorry.
2. [Download TShock and start the server](https://tshock.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TSHOCKPLUGINS/Installation+Instructions).
3. Join the server via multiplayer, using 127.0.0.1 as the IP and the default port.
4. Become an admin, as described in the instructions linked in step 2.
5. Enter `/spawnboss wof` in the in-game chat, preferably while in the Underworld.

Answer (score 15):

The only way to summon the wall of flesh involves killing the town guide.

This is not a great loss, as the guide respawns quite quickly, and there is no penalty for killing an NPC.

Answer (score -3):

if you had the cheat i had, you could spawn him in which got banned because it gave you any item you wanted for nothing. Like, if you wanted the best items in the game before hard-mode, you could get them for free and anything else. But it got banned in 2016 so everyone that had it got it took away.

---

But for your question, what you can do is start a server, invite a few people, make them and yourself admins, then type the command for spawning the Wall of Flesh and, Tada! Done!